# Where, how and when I can acquire HM's?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have HM Strength and HM Cut.

I would love to fly around this new beautiful world but I'm curious when it will be possible.

Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### X/Y HM Locations

**Cut** - Parfum Palace - In the maze in the garden at the back of the palace

**Fly** - Courmaline City - From Professor Sycamore in a cut scene - can be used outside of battle after defeating Ramos in Coumarine City Gym and earning the Plant badge

**Surf** - Shalour City - From Calem/Serena, after defeating Korrina at the top of the Tower of Mastery - can be used already by the time you obtain it, after beating Shalour City Gym

**Strength** - Cyllage City - From Grant

**Waterfall** - Route 19 - From Shauna

Also useful to note - **Rock Smash** is no longer a HM but you can get it in Ambrette town, from a girl outside the Pokemon centre.

The same goes for **Flash** which is now a "nice-to-have" tool for lowering the amount of fights in caves. You can get it from your Dancing friend in Glittering cave.

Comment: I think you need to beat Grant to be able to use Strength. Maybe not though.

Comment: Is it possible to buy Rock Smash anywhere, or are you stuck with only one copy per game?

Comment: You get only one copy, but TM's and HM's can be used infinite times.

Answer (score 3):

[TM and HM list](http://www.serebii.net/xy/tmhm.shtml) will show you every TM and HM you can get, and how to do so.

You do get the Fly HM in Courmaline City from the professor..

Comment: You cannot use fly outside of battle until you beat the Gym. I believe the grass gym specifically.