# Where do I get HM02 Fly in Pokemon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am getting tired of running from city to city, so now I am on the quest for HM02. Do I get it through the main story, or is there somewhere I must go non-quest specific?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135877/where-how-and-when-i-can-acquire-hms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HM02 Fly is received in Coumarine City (4th Gym Badge). Professor Sycamore will give it to you as part of the story.