# What field moves are available and what do they do?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Obviously all of the [HMs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/135877/9350) are usable outside of battle, but there are also moves such as Teleport, Flash, and Sweet Scent which are usable outside of battle as well.

What are all of these moves, and what effect do they have in the field?

Comment: Bulbapedia has a list up to gen 5: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Field_move_(main_series) I'm not sure if any new field moves were introduced in gen 6 (none that I've seen anyway) though Flash's effect is different, now reduces the encounter rate.

Answer (score 3):

I went [here](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/move-descriptions.3489718/) and checked out all the move descriptions that had the word "also" in it. As Ben Brocka said, I don't think there are any new ones, but here:

Format: Name | Type | Category | Base Power | Accuracy | PP | Description

- **Rock Smash** | Fighting | Physical | 40 | 100 | 15 | The user attacks
  with a punch. This may also lower the target's Defense stat. This
  move can also shatter rocks in the field.
- **Dig** | Ground | Physical |
  80 | 100 | 10 | The user burrows, then attacks on the next turn. It
  can also be used to exit dungeons.
- **Milk Drink** | Normal | Status | --
  | -- | 10 | The user restores its own HP by up to half of its max HP.
  May also be used in the field to heal HP.
- **Soft-Boiled** | Normal |
  Status | -- | -- | 10 | The user restores its own HP by up to half of
  its max HP. May also be used in the field to heal HP.
- **Sweet Scent** |
  Normal | Other | -- | 100 | 20 | A sweet scent that harshly lowers
  opposing Pokémon's evasiveness. This also lures wild Pokémon if used
  in places such as tall grass.
- **Teleport** | Psychic | Status | - | - |
  20 | Use it to flee from any wild Pokemon. It can also warp to the
  last Pokemon Center visited.
- **Flash** | Normal | Status | -- | 100 | 20
  | The user flashes a bright light that cuts the target's accuracy.

I realize flash doesn't have that "also" word, but it seems to lower encounter rate in caves, according to the hiker who gives it to you. Chatter doesn't appear to be a field move anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Fly** is given by **Professor Sycamore** in **Coumarine City** and can be used outside of battle after beating **Coumarine City Gym**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While you are completely free to answer old questions (this question is 2 years old), you are not likely to get any reputation out of them.

Comment: Also, it does not completely answer the question

Comment: This does answer the question, though not with as much detail as the accepted answer. More importantly,fly is an essential field move, and is not listed in the other answer.